# How to refresh the jquery dialog for next use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HI,I am using  a div content to push in jquery dialog.After opening for the second time i want to refresh the dialog with the same content of div without affecting my code.How can i do that? Help me pls..The code is like:

Jquery dialog code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#atendeePopup" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width:610,
    height:680,
    show: "fold",
    hide: "core"
    });

    $('.flora.ui-dialog').css({position:"fixed"});

    $( "#widgetAtendeeIcon").click(function() {
        $( "#atendeePopup" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<div id=""#atendeePopup" >
<p>My div content here</>
</div>
```

Comment: You just want to open the dialog again? Or are you changing the content of the div somehow. I didn't get what you meant by refresh.

Comment: One more thing, I think you declared your div id in the wrong way. Try: `<div id="atendeePopup">`

Comment: @Anthony-When i open the dialog for the second time whatever changes i made in the previous dialog it will remain same.For ex.,If i change the color of text in text box in first dialog,then the same color will be applied for next use of the dialog also.the property for the text in text box remains same.It should be as given in html div.But it takes the changed style for dynamic text box.

Comment: @Anthony-It was a mistake while copying..I have written correctly in html..like u showed here..sorry for that mistake during doing copy the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming by `refresh` you mean put back in the original data, and here we gooo:

```
$(function () {
    if ($("#atendeePopup").data('orig') == undefined) {
        $("#atendeePopup").data('orig', $("#atendeePopup").html());
    }
    $("#atendeePopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 610,
        height: 680,
        show: "fold",
        hide: "core"
    });
    $('.flora.ui-dialog').css({
        position: "fixed"
    });

    $("#widgetAtendeeIcon").click(function () {
        if ($("#atendeePopup").data('orig') != undefined) { //update to orig
            $("#atendeePopup").html($("#atendeePopup").data('orig'));
    }
    $("#atendeePopup").dialog("open");
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If  I use your code then its refreshing my whole html page..But i want to refresh the content of dialog only.

Comment: ummm yes, that is what my code does...it just refreshes the dialog

Comment: Neal-I just want to refresh the dialog.Not the html page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your HTML is invalid (maybe not copy & paste):

```
<div id="#atendeePopup" >
   <p>My div content here</p>
</div>
```

you can change the content of your popup by calling:

```
$("#atendeePopup").html("<p>This is the new content</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as setting `$(<div name> <input name>).val('')` for each of the inputs in the form. If you include your code, we can give more specific advice.

Comment: @neal - yes, it was pseudocode. Give me *some* benefit of the doubt... :)